# Highcharts legend displaying abnormal Pipe line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When I enable Legend it displays an awkward Line that irritates me I have searched a lot about it but I can't find any example which contains this line  and the second problem is with background of chart.Background should be white.

Code:

```
var  type = 'column';
    ChartSelectorObj[ChartID] = new Highcharts.Chart(Div,{
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            type: type,
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                    if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                        var chart = this;

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if (e.point.drillDownSerieData != null) {
                                debugger;
                                chart.hideLoading();
                                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, e.point.drillDownSerieData[0]);
                            }
                        }, 10);
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled:true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                //stacking: 'normal',
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:,.0f}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            colorByPoint: true,
            dashStyle: 'Solid'
        }]
        ,
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b> of total<br/>'
        }

    });
```

[Screenshot of my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku2yO.png)

Comment: *The pipe line* is a [color Axis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis)

Comment: @Core972 How can I remove this ??

Comment: The code you have posted does not contain the elements you want to remove. If you post a more complete example where the elements can be seen, it is much easier to help you remove them.

Comment: @ewolden is right, colorAxis is an additional module (another javascript file) loaded after highcharts

Comment: @ewolden Actually I am not defining colorAxis . it's appearing by default.

Comment: For now I write this css code to hide ColorAxis
<style>
        .highcharts-legend-item highcharts-undefined-series highcharts-color-undefined {
            visibility:hidden !important
        }
    </style>      

But I think it's not a better approach.

Comment: You still didn't provide the code of your app which would allow us to debug the problem efficient enough. Please tell me, which modules you imported, in what situation the problem occurs? We need more informations.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable the color axis, it depends on where did you defined it. It can be defined in your general chart configuration object as `colorAxis` or inside of your `series`, but in most common cases it's the first one option, so you just need to delete the `colorAxis` definition.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis

Kind regards!

Comment: Instead of giving the 'downvote', please explain here why my answer deserves to it. I would like to stress @Salman Jamael Sunny doesn't provide me with any configuration code of his chart, so I could only guess why it's visible. If you doesn't defined the `colorAxis` anywhere in your code, I need to see whole code of your chart to give you more precise answer.